# How to read excel into R using read.csv

Tags: excel, import, read.csv

I have a dataset in excel that looks like this.

[image]

The create_time column is a wired time format. But when you click on a cell in that column in excel, the actual date time is shown on left top corner. My task is to import this excel into R using read.csv, and then convert the create_time column to actual date time format.

If I just use read.csv("file.csv"), the create_time would be in weird time format, which is not what I want. I know that I can convert the date time format in excel manually, or I can use read_excel to read this file, but my task is to import this file using read.csv...

Does anyone have any idea how to approach this? I would really appreciate it!